# upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

After upgrading from version 12.04 to 14.04.1.

I get a notification: System program problem detected. Do you want to report the problem now or cancel? I cancelled it and seems working fine. But, I would like to know what does it mean and how to solve it.